# coffeescript: request is returning what looks to be a stream

Tags: javascript, stream, coffeescript, request

have a function to poll a SOAP endpoint

```
someFunction = (task={}, callback)->

    req = {}
    req.body = buildEnvelope(task) # this works correctly
    result = {}

    request.post(
        {url: <<wsdl string>>, body: req.body, headers: {"Content-Type": "text/xml"}},
        (error, response, body) ->
            if not error and response.statusCode is 200
                result = buildHash(body) # this builds a hash from the result, correctly
                return result
    )
```

all the internal functions are working as intended, but when I try to do something like `console.log(someFunction(hash, ()->)`, I get back weird content:

```
{ domain: null,
  _events: { error: [Function], complete: [Function], pipe: [Function] },
  _maxListeners: 10,
  readable: true,
  writable: true,
  body: <Buffer 3c 3f 78 6d 6c 20 76 65 72 73 69 6f 6e 3d 22 31 2e 30 22 20 65 6e 63 6f 64 69 6e 67 3d 22 55 54 46 2d 38 22 3f 3e 20 3c 53 4f 41 50 2d 45 4e 56 3a 45 6e ...>,
  headers:
   { 'Content-Type': 'text/xml',...}
```

which looks like a stream object of some flavor coming back from `request`. I'm guessing that this is because I put the `return` statement in the middle of the `request.post()` call, but if I put it outside of that call, it returns an empty hash, because the return happens before the POST action takes place.

What's the best way to get the hash that I expect as a result of running `someFunction()` to be returned by the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That return value is whatever `request.post` returns. If a CoffeeScript function doesn't have an explicit `return` statement, then it returns the value of the last executed statement; in your case, that would be the `request.post` call.

Nothing probably cares about what your `request.post` callback returns so your:

```
return result
```

is pointless. If you want to get something from an asynchronous call back out to the outside world then you need to use the `callback` parameter:

```
someFunction = (task={}, callback)->
    #...
    request.post(
        {url: <<wsdl string>>, body: req.body, headers: {"Content-Type": "text/xml"}},
        (error, response, body) ->
            if not error and response.statusCode is 200
                callback(buildHash(body)) # <------------------
    )

someFunction({...}, (hash) ->
    # Do something interesting with `hash` in here...
)
```

The real calling convention for `callback` would, of course, depend on what specifically you need to return.